# почему метод Ньютона не сходится?

Tags: математика

При нахождении точки экстремума метод Ньютона может не найти решения, если начальное приближение слишком далеко от искомого, но почему?

Comment: Кратко? Потому что у него есть свои необходимые и достаточные условия сходимости, которые могут не выполняться вдалеке от искомой точки. Примерно как у самолета есть своя грузоподъемность, и хрен легкий "кукурузник" взлетит, если в него напихать загрузку из какого-нибудь "Ил-96"...

Answer (score 3):

в градиентном спуске есть проблема оврагов - нахождение локального минимума вместо глобального

по сути здесь тоже самое - при определённом виде функции, начальной точке Xn и шаге можно проскочить перегиб и свалиться в другой локальный экстремум или уйти на бесконечность - например когда экстремум слева от диапазона, а функция монотонно убывает

а вообще это описано в **теореме Канторовича**.

Answer (score 3):

Короткий ответ:

метод Ньютона предназначен для поиска корней, в предположениии, что начальное приближение находится достаточно близко к преполагаемому корню уравнения. Если начальнео приближение далеко - то "магия" этого метода перестаёт работать. Так же, как если функция, к которой применяется мктод - не гладкая (то есть, есть точки, в которых нельзя построить касательную к графику)

Теперь чуть чуть подробнее:

Если Вы откроете статью о методе в википедии,там перечисляются следующие условия применимости метода:

функция должна быть ограничена;

функция должна быть гладкой, дважды дифференцируемой;

её первая производная равномерно отделена от нуля;

её вторая производная должна быть равномерно ограничена.

Теперь легко придумать пример, когда метод Ньютона не будет работать. Например,Ю хитрый график, который имеет локальный экстремум недалеко от корня. Если Ваше первое приближение покадает вблизи этого экстремума - то касательная к гарфику почти горизонтальная, а точка пересечения её с осью х находится далеко и от экстремума, и от корня.